# CHARINDEX returns the wrong result in some COLLATIONs when searching for thorn (character 254)

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation, charindex

**Overview**

`CHARINDEX` is returning the wrong value occasionally when using a collation sequence like:

```
Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

but works with a collation sequence like:

```
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

This has been encountered on MS SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2016.

**Examples**

Assume the database collation sequence is:

```
Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

- `print  CHARINDEX( CHAR(254), 'Tþ' )` -- returns 2 which is Correct
- `print  CHARINDEX( CHAR(254), 'Th'  )` -- returns 1 which is WRONG
- `print  CHARINDEX( CHAR(253), 'Th'  )` -- returns 0 which is Correct
- `print  CHARINDEX( CHAR(254) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, 'Thþ' Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)` -- returns 3 which is Correct
- `print  CHARINDEX( CHAR(254) Collate Latin1_General_CI_AS, 'Thþ' Collate Latin1_General_CI_AS)` -- returns 1 which is WRONG

Is there a known error with the `Latin1...` collation sequences?

Comment: Have you tried using NCHAR and N'Tþ'?

Comment: Unfortunately using
`print  CHARINDEX( NCHAR(254) , N'Th' )` still returns 1 which is WRONG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't anything specific to SQL Server.

In C#

```
string.Compare("þ", "th", false, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(1033))
```

returns `0` indicating the strings compare equal.

Or in notepad clicking "Replace all" below

[image]

leads to

[image]

In SQL Server collations that do not start with "SQL" use windows collation rules.

For those in most locales (Iceland being an exception) the [thorn character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_(letter)) `þ` expands to `th`.

There is more information about this specific case in this post by Michael S. Kaplan [Every rose has it's Þ....](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2011/10/13/10224477.html). That blog has a wealth of information about windows collations. Expansions are [described in more detail here](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2007/09/15/4924008.html).

If you don't want these semantics you need to use a collation (likely SQL or binary) with the semantics that you do want (perhaps via an explicit `collate` clause).

Answer (score 2):

This will return the correct result:

```
select CHARINDEX( NCHAR(254) Collate Latin1_General_BIN2, N'Tþ' Collate Latin1_General_BIN2)
select CHARINDEX( NCHAR(254) Collate Latin1_General_BIN2, N'Th' Collate Latin1_General_BIN2 )
select CHARINDEX( NCHAR(253) Collate Latin1_General_BIN2, N'Th' Collate Latin1_General_BIN2 )
select CHARINDEX( NCHAR(254) Collate Latin1_General_BIN2, N'Thþ' Collate Latin1_General_BIN2)
```

Documentation says:

> **Using Binary Collations**
>
> The following considerations will help you to decide whether old or new binary collations are appropriate for your Microsoft SQL Server
>   implementation. Support for both BIN and BIN2 collations will continue
>   in future SQL Server releases.
>
> Binary collations sort data based on the sequence of coded values defined in a particular code page. A binary collation in SQL Server
>   defines the language locale and the ANSI code page to be used,
>   enforcing a binary sort order. Binary collations are useful in
>   achieving improved application performance due to their relative
>   simplicity.
>
> Previous binary collations in SQL Server performed an incomplete code-point-to-code-point comparison for Unicode data, in that older
>   SQL Server binary collations compared the first character as WCHAR,
>   followed by a byte-by-byte comparison. For backward compatibility
>   reasons, existing binary collation semantics will not be changed.
>
> **Guidelines for Using Binary Collations**
>
> If your Microsoft SQL Server 2005 applications interact with older versions of SQL Server that use binary collations, continue to use
>   binary. Binary collations may be a more suitable choice for mixed
>   environments.
>
> **Guidelines for Using BIN2 Collations**
>
> Binary collations in this release of SQL Server include a new set of pure code-point comparison collations. Customers can choose to
>   migrate to the new binary collations to take advantage of true
>   code-point comparisons, and they should utilize the new binary
>   collations for development of new applications. The new BIN2 suffix
>   identifies collation names that implement the new code-point collation
>   semantics. In addition, a new comparison flag is added corresponding
>   to BIN2 for the new binary sort. Advantages include simpler
>   application development and clearer semantics.

IE. `BIN2` collation is equivalent to using `Ordinal` in `C#` wrt to `charindex`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately we have to use the collation Latin1_General_CI_AS in this database. I am keen to know why the Latin1_General_CI_AS collation sequence does not behave correctly with CHARINDEX and CHAR(254)

Comment: You can override collation in all queries, doesnt matter what the data is stored in. E.g. we override it for all order by to get per-language sorting

Comment: @Gazza I've seen plenty of problems with this sort of operations, and the solution is usually go for the _BIN (or _BIN2) collation. As Cine already said, no need to change at the database or table level, you can specify this on the statement level.